# How do you submit a form with the model "submit" button

Tags: typescript, sabre

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm trying to work on some basic forms for Sabre web. I can easily make a new button and submit my form commands through that but I cannot figure out how to make the basic "submit" button you can create in the model do anything. For reference here is my options

```
WFRBuilder():void {
    const options = {
        title: 'WFR Builder',
        actions: [{
            className: 'app.common.views.Button',
            caption: 'Cancel',
            actionName: 'cancel',
            type: 'secondary'
        },
            {
                className: 'app.common.views.Button',
                caption: 'Submit',
                actionName: 'submit-pnr',
                type: 'secondary'
            }]
    };
```

But how do I trigger that button press?

Answer (score 0):

I'm transitioning from sabre script writing to sabre red apps.

I found this example/sample it has textboxes to collect information and then submit button to send to sabre.

Location: C:\SDK\red-app-sdk-3.0-20.11.6\samples File: com.sabre.redapp.example3.web.customworkflow-1.0.5-SNAPSHOT-v20201016-1358.zip

This is the main processor file that initiates the data in html, to ts, to sabre. C:\SDK\workspace\com-sabre-test3-web-module\src\code
**Main.ts**

The modal shown in sabre comes from template dir. These are HTML pages with boxes/drop downs etc. C:\SDK\workspace\com-sabre-test3-web-module\src\templates
**PnrView.html**

Transmit to sabre C:\SDK\workspace\com-sabre-test3-web-module\src\code\view
**Pnr.View.ts**

**This is the button section in Main.ts**

private createPNR(): void {

```
    const pnrOptions = {
        title: 'Add to PNR',
        actions: [{
            className: 'app.common.views.Button',
            caption: 'Cancel',
            actionName: 'cancel',
            type: 'secondary'
        }, {
            className: 'app.common.views.Button',
            caption: 'Submit',
            actionName: 'submit-pnr',
            type: 'secondary'
        }]
    };

    const tenDaysAheadFlight = '1' + datesService.getNow().add(10, 'days').format('DDMMM').toUpperCase() + 'LGWKRK';

    getService(LayerService).showInModal(new PnrView({
        model: {flight: tenDaysAheadFlight}
    }), pnrOptions , {display: 'areaView'});
}
```